# What value does using a layoutinflator add

Tags: android, android-layout

Below are 2 pieces of code. In each one there is an inner class called IconicAdapter. In the getView method, we create an instance of View called row. My question is... What is the difference between the ways that we've instantiated row ie. using a layout inflator and using super.getview(). If this example doesnt make the difference clear then please explain a specific example that I would use layout inflator for:

Sample 1:

```
public class DynamicDemo extends ListActivity {
  TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
          "sit", "amet",
          "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
          "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
          "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
          "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                              int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }

  class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IconicAdapter() {
      super(DynamicDemo.this, R.layout.row, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(items[position]);

      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      if (items[position].length()>4) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
      }

      return(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Sample 2:

```
public class DynamicDemo extends ListActivity {
  TextView selection;
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
          "sit", "amet",
          "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
          "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
          "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
          "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
                              int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
  }

  class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    IconicAdapter() {
      super(DynamicDemo.this, R.layout.row, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(items[position]);

      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      if (items[position].length()>4) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
      }

      return(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, which uses a `LayoutInflater` you inflate a layout file which will be `View` for the `ListView`'s row. This let's you completely override the way the row's `View`  is being built in the `getView` method. You would generally want to use this as it is very flexible and puts you in total control(but also you have to take care and optimize the `getView` method, not like you did in the samples you provided).

In the second case you're using the `View` which is returned by the super class `getView` method. In this case you're letting the `ArrayAdapter` super class implement the `View` like it wants and then use this simple `View` to further update/modify it. This method is particular useful when you're happy with the way the super class builds the row view and only plan to make small changes to the already built `View`. For example let's say that you build a custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter` and in this adapter you want to have alternate backgrounds color for the rows views. Then you would implement the `getView` method like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // let the superclass build the View and set the data on it 
      View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      // we want to modify the View's background so we do
      if (position % 2 == 0) {
          row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      } else {
          row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      } 
      return row;
}
```

We could have used the `LayoutInflator` but for just a small change in appearance is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

In the theory there are no diffrence at all, but in the practice there are.

You are ignoring `convertView` argument, but `ArrayAdapter` don't.
convertView is tricky optimization for buttery smooth scrolling. When you scrolling, listview periodically calls `getView` method on supplied adapter. In your case (sample #2), you creating many object that litters GC heap. Moreover, you are inflating your layout from XML each time. `ArrayAdapter.getView` instead of creating new objects reuses old, just calls textView.setText (btw, you call label.setText twice: first in super.getView, and second `label.setText(items[position])`)

In addition, you quering `View`s instances each time in `getView` by calling `findViewById`. Instead of that try to use [`ViewHolder` pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).